# SPARQL delete query dotNetRDF does not modify RDF file

Tags: sparql, dotnetrdf

I like to delete a RDF tuple from a RDF file using dotNetRDF. Here is the code I'm using

```java
  public void deleteDest(string destID)
    {
        TripleStore store = new TripleStore();

        Graph rdf = new Graph();

        FileLoader.Load(rdf, rdfFilePath, new RdfXmlParser());
        store.Add(rdf);

        SparqlUpdateParser parser = new SparqlUpdateParser();
        SparqlParameterizedString cmdString = new SparqlParameterizedString();

        cmdString.CommandText = "PREFIX  j.0: <http://www.example.org/destDetails#>"
            + "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"
            + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"
            + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
            + "DELETE  "
            + "WHERE { "
            + "        ?dest  j.0:ID  \"" + destID + "\" "
             + "}";

        SparqlUpdateCommandSet cmds = parser.ParseFromString(cmdString);
        LeviathanUpdateProcessor processor = new LeviathanUpdateProcessor(store);
        processor.ProcessCommandSet(cmds);
        rdf.SaveToFile(rdfFilePath);

    }
```

Here is the structure of my RDF file

```xml
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://www.example.org/destDetails#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org/destDetails#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="&ns0;0165a659-54ea-4e80-bee7-9d3951d47ae3">
    <ns0:ID>0165a659-54ea-4e80-bee7-9d3951d47ae3</ns0:ID>
    <ns0:destination rdf:resource="&ns0;VELES" />
    <ns0:distrName>Test Test</ns0:distrName>
    <ns0:hasTimeStart>17:00</ns0:hasTimeStart>
    <ns0:hasTimeStop>17:55</ns0:hasTimeStop>
    <ns0:moneyOneDir>130 den.</ns0:moneyOneDir>
    <ns0:moneyTwoDir>---</ns0:moneyTwoDir>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

However, no changes are applied to the RDF file.

Comment: It looks like you're writing your model out to disk, which is good, and I suspect that the problem isn't there.  Can you print the model to standard output rather than writing it to disk?  I expect that you either: aren't passing the `destID` that you're expecting, or that it is a typed literal, so you need to actually use `?dest j.0:ID "..."^^xsd:string`.

Comment: I suppose that literal is not a problem, because the same destID that is input parameter in the method I used for SELECT SPARQL and is returning a result

Comment: Even if the text form is the same, if inserting it causes a _typed_ literal to be inserted into the graph, then attempting to remove an _untyped_ literal wouldn't remove the triple that got inserted.  It's easy to test;  just add `^^xsd:string` to your SPARQL query and see if the results change.

Comment: I tried but there is still no modification to the rdf file

Comment: Hmm… If you try saving to a new file (i.e., a different path), what are the results?

Comment: Duplicate question asked and answered at <http://answers.semanticweb.com//questions/24051/sparql-query-delete-does-not-modify-a-rdf-file>

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your update operates over the default graph but that your dataset only contains a named graph.

```
FileLoader.Load(rdf, rdfFilePath, new RdfXmlParser());
store.Add(rdf);
```

When you do the above this loads data into your graph and assigns that graph a name based on the source of the data - in your case it gets a `file://` URI.  Then when you add it to the store the store uses the current name of the graph (from the `BaseUri` property of the graph) and adds it as a named graph.

However your `DELETE` only references the default graph which is empty in your example and your named graph is not modified in any way.  There are several different ways to fix this problem.

#### 1 - Construct your dataset explicitly

You can specify that your named graph be treated as the default graph like so:

```
// Create a dataset and use the named graph as the default graph
InMemoryDataset ds = new InMemoryDataset(store, rdf.BaseUri);
// Use the dataset to create the processor
LeviathanUpdateProcessor processor = new LeviathanUpdateProcessor(ds);
```

#### 2 - Add your named graph as the default graph

You can make your named graph be treated as the default graph by removing its name before you add it to the store:

```
FileLoader.Load(rdf, rdfFilePath, new RdfXmlParser());
rdf.BaseUri = null; // Remove the name from the graph
// If the graph has no name it is added as the default graph
store.Add(rdf);
```

#### 3 - Rewrite your update

You can rewrite your `DELETE` to reference the named graph explicitly:

```
cmdString.CommandText = @"PREFIX j.0: <http://www.example.org/destDetails#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
DELETE WHERE 
{
  GRAPH @graph { ?dest j.0:ID @destID }
}";

cmdString.SetUri("graph", rdf.BaseUri);
cmdString.SetLiteral("destID", destID);
```

Note that I've used [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) for readability and injected the parameters via `SetUri()` and `SetLiteral()` rather than string concatenation.

Comment: This code throws me URI could not be null exception. I put rdf.BaseUri = new Uri("http://www.example.org/destDetails") and the code deletes the tuple j.0:ID property. I like to delete the whole rdf:about tuple with all properties. Could you give me some idea?

Comment: Which code?  If the `BaseUri` is `null` then `cmd.SetUri()` would give that error.

Comment: If you want to delete all triples related to the triple you identified then add `?dest ?p ?o` as an additional triple pattern to your `DELETE`

Comment: cmd.SetUri() gives URI could not be null exception

Comment: Yes that is expected, if your graph doesn't have a URI then there is no need to use the `GRAPH` form of the `DELETE` since an unnamed graph will be treated as the default graph

Comment: Could you please edit your code from 3-Rewrite your update to see how to delete the whole tuple @RobV

Comment: @vikifor If you don't understand how to write the SPARQL update to achieve your aim then that is a separate question unrelated to this problem that you had with dotNetRDF and should be asked as a new question

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra space `\"" + destID + "\" "` (marked with an X --> \"" + destID + "\"X")

Comment: I tried with no extra whitespace. There were no modification to the file.

Comment: As I noted on <http://answers.semanticweb.com//questions/24051/sparql-query-delete-does-not-modify-a-rdf-file> -- 

That extra space goes after the quotation mark that closes the destID value/string, and before the closing brace "}". It's not the issue.