# add and delete query from N3 using dotnet rdf in C#

Tags: c#, sparql, dotnetrdf

I had changed my RDF file to N3 and I am using it in C# with dotNetRDF. I can parse and query on this N3 file. My question is how to add and delete an statement to my N3 files. It is a sample N3 statement, I need to add and delete such statement to my N3 files.

```
###  http://example.org/Sample#A

:A rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOF :B.
```

These statements make my hierarchy, so by adding or deleting a statement, these should be in the right place.

Comment: @joshua taylor , i hope u can help me

Comment: I'm not a dotNetRDF user, so I'm not sure how much help I'll be here.  However, since you've tagged this with SPARQL as well, you may find [this recent question about updating files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18173387/1281433) useful. I don't expect that the particular format (RDF/XML, N3, etc.) should matter much.  It should be a matter of reading the data in, modifying the in-memory model, and writing the model back out to disk.

Comment: Close reasons for questions include: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself." and  "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  Please show us the code that you've written so far, as well as the results it produces, and tell us what you expected the results to be.

Answer (score 1):

The [Working with Graphs](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Working%20with%20Graphs) documentation covers the basics of doing this just via API calls as opposed to using full blown SPARQL Update.

Specifically you will be interested in the `Assert()` method of an `IGraph` implementation which is used to add new triples to a graph, the counterpart `Retract()` method removes triples from a graph.

If you are new to dotNetRDF I would suggest reading through the basic tutorial in our [User Guide](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/User%20Guide) which starts with the [Library Overview](https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide/Library%20Overview)