# Delete RDF tuple using dotNetRDF

Tags: rdf, sparql, dotnetrdf

I'd like to delete a RDF tuple using dotNetRDF. Here is my RDF file:

```xml
<rdf:RDF xml:base="http://www.example.org/destDetails#" 
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" 
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" 
         xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org/destDetails#" 
         xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="&ns0;0165a659-54ea-4e80-bee7-9d3951d47ae3">
    <ns0:ID>0165a659-54ea-4e80-bee7-9d3951d47ae3</ns0:ID>
    <ns0:destination rdf:resource="&ns0;VELES" />
    <ns0:distrName>Test Test</ns0:distrName>
    <ns0:hasTimeStart>17:00</ns0:hasTimeStart>
    <ns0:hasTimeStop>17:55</ns0:hasTimeStop>
    <ns0:moneyOneDir>130 den.</ns0:moneyOneDir>
    <ns0:moneyTwoDir>---</ns0:moneyTwoDir>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Here is the code I am using:

```c#
        TripleStore magacinTorki = new TripleStore();
        //kreiranje na graf
        Graph rdf = new Graph();
        // Create a dataset and use the named graph as the default graph
        FileLoader.Load(rdf, rdfDatoteka, new RdfXmlParser());
        rdf.BaseUri = new Uri("http://www.example.org/destDetails"); // Remove the name from the graph
        // If the graph has no name it is added as the default graph
        magacinTorki.Add(rdf);
        SparqlUpdateParser parser = new SparqlUpdateParser();
        SparqlParameterizedString cmdString = new SparqlParameterizedString();

        cmdString.CommandText = @"PREFIX  ns0: <http://www.example.org/destDetails#>"
            + " PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"
            + " DELETE "
            + " WHERE  {"
            + " GRAPH @graph {  ?dest ?p ?o"
            + " ?dest ns0:nodeID @destID} }";

        cmdString.SetUri("graph",rdf.BaseUri);
        cmdString.SetLiteral("destID",destID);
        SparqlUpdateCommandSet cmds = parser.ParseFromString(cmdString);
        LeviathanUpdateProcessor processor = new LeviathanUpdateProcessor(magacinTorki);
        processor.ProcessCommandSet(cmds);
        rdf.SaveToFile(rdfDatoteka);
```

However nothing is happening to the RDF file.

---

This code works fine for me, because I was not asked to delete the triples using SPARQL

```java
        Graph rdf = new Graph();
        // Create a dataset and use the named graph as the default graph
        FileLoader.Load(rdf, rdfDatoteka, new RdfXmlParser());
        rdf.BaseUri = new Uri("http://www.example.org/destDetails");
        INode n = rdf.GetUriNode(new Uri("http://www.example.org/destDetails#" + destID));
        if (n != null)
        {
            rdf.Retract(rdf.GetTriplesWithSubject(n));
        }
        rdf.SaveToFile(rdfDatoteka);
```

where `destID` is a subject of all triples.

Comment: What didn't work in @RobV's [answer to the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18192355/1281433) that you didn't accept?  This looks like the same question.  He did comment "If you don't understand how to write the SPARQL update to achieve your aim then that is a separate question unrelated to this problem", but this looks like the same question.

Comment: I like to delete all properties of the tuple and the tuple itself. The RobV answer deletes only nodeID property.

Comment: He said in [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173387/sparql-delete-query-dotnetrdf-does-not-modify-rdf-file/18192355#comment26665701_18192355), "If you want to delete all triples related to the triple you identified then add `?dest ?p ?o` as an additional triple pattern to your `DELETE`".

Comment: Also, a note on terminology:  generally speaking, triples (i.e., 3-tuples) don't have properties.  Each triple has the form {subject  predicate object}.  In your data, you have seven triples (letting X stand for the node): {X ID …}; {X destination …}; {X distrName "Test test"}; and so on. Each triple {X p o} may be viewed as stating that "X has value o for property p".  It sounds like you just want to delete all the triples that assert properties of X, which @RobV's earlier comment explained how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your query does not actually match your data which is why your `DELETE` has no effect.

In your data you have `ns0:ID` but in your `DELETE` you try to match against `ns0:nodeID` - therefore no data will be matched and nothing will be deleted.